# Can we use CONCAT and JOIN together in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables table_a and table_b respectively, I want to add two columns together that is concat, but one column  from table_a and other from table_b is it possible?

Comment: Well, did you try it? (http://sqlfiddle.com may be of use here)

Comment: Did you try it, and what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Try something like this:

```
SELECT a.ID, CONCAT(a.name,' ',b.surname) AS FULL_Name
  FROM table_a a JOIN table_b b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3c01/2)